# Using input output file for coding questions in Python

Tags: python

I want a way to use input from a input.txt and show result to output.txt using **Python**. Maybe in VScode or sublime.

I know this way.

```py
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r') 
sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

But using this we ***cant work with any type of input. E.g. it won't work when input is space seperated. Like `2 3`.***

I need a generalized way in Python, just like we use code below in C++, for dealing with any type of input

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
```

EXAMPLE-

Consider the problem to find single unique number from given list in each test case and output the result.

Input-

```
3 
5
5 5 8 8 2 
5 
1 2 2 3 3
7
2 2 1 1 6 3 6
```

Output-

```
2
1
3
```

Please let me know how to accept these input.
Even if you don't mention the logic it would do the needful. Just **guide me to take input and output for the problem**.

Also, **will it take input from online judge** also ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to do the same, but in generalized way just like C++ code given does. For competitive programming contests to save time.

Comment: Can u show the contents of ur file?

Comment: "E.g. it won't work when input is space seperated. Like 2 3." What are you talking about? There's nothing that prevents you from reading such a file in Python, and the C++ function you show doesn't change anything either - if the file was open for reading, then reopening it for reading doesn't matter. You need to show the *actual problem your code exhibits* - show what's in the file and how you tried to read it, and explain exactly what went wrong.

Comment: @skaul05 I have added it in question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with the usage of `sys.stdin`. `sys.stdin` will open your input file but to extract the input you need to iterate over it like below loop.

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r') 
for line in sys.stdin.readlines(): # iteration over each line
    first,second = map(int,line.split())
    print(first,second)
```

Assuming your `input.txt` file contains input like you mentioned

```
2 3
4 5
6 7
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Comment: Please guide me for input in the updated problem.

Comment: U can iterate your input accordingly. Each iteartion of your for loop will give you a line. U can add ur logic accordingly